# ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream is not working in my code

Tags: java

The below given code is returning *null* when I am loading the *property file*. Kindly go through the code and suggest me the changes.

```
    constantProp = new Properties();

    try {

        // Loads the constants.properties file
        InputStream constantPropFile = ClassLoader.class
                .getResourceAsStream("/ConstantFiles/" 
                        + ".properties");
        System.out.println(constantPropFile);
        constantProp.load(constantPropFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        // e.printStackTrace();
        log.equals("Constant Property file not found");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        // e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("Can't Load constants.properties property  
   file ");
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is `"/ConstantFiles/" + ".properties"`?

Comment: What is the exact location of `ConstantFiles.properties` and your class ?

Comment: ConstantFiles is the folder name

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the method `getResourceAsStream` then it describes:

> The search order is described in the documentation for {@link getResource(String)}.
>
> An input stream for reading the resource, or null if the resource
>   could not be found

And make sure the Link is working properly.

So If you are trying to load a property file from your local machine or from a  path that you already know, then you can use below code for loading property files:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("/ConstantFiles/.properties"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the file name. Your comment in code says "Loads the constants.properties file" but your code is trying load a file called ".properties" located at folder "/ConstantFiles/". So, it seems that your issue could be just that you are missing the file name.

Just in case you don't know it, "getResourceAsStream" will try to look for the file at your classpath. Please check that the folder "ConstantFiles" is in your classpath (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))

Comment: How do i check the classpath ?If "/ConstantFiles" is not present in classpath what do I need to use?

Comment: Although you define the property file name as `some.properties` you will get the same error.

Comment: @PS. If "/ConstantFiles" is not in classpath you can just load the file using "FileInputStream". For instance: `InputStream constantPropFile = new FileInputStream("/etc/your_app/ConstantFiles/constants.properties")`